# User interface resources for android

Tags: android

I have a background in java and i would like to learn how to design user interfaces in 24 hours for android.Can anyone give me an advice on how to go about it in terms of resources.

Answer (score 1):

I hope Android Developer Site has more info about UI..

You can use this link.. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

I advice you to study about UI simultaneously with working on Android development, so that you will be familiarized with terms as well as what to use when and where..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you go through the newly launched Android design website:
http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

You can learn about styling, colors, patterns, typography, interaction patterns, navigation and much more.